# Snowflake insert overwrite behaviour

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

If I execute **INSERT OVERWRITE TABLEA** statement and it takes 5 minutes to run. During its execution if I run **SELECT * FROM TABLEA** is there any possibility that I will not see any data? because of **INSERT OVERWRITE** first truncate the data and then load it.

I experienced that the data was not there in TABLEA but after the pipeline run it i saw the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default isolation level in Snowflake is Read Committed; which means you can't read uncommitted data. The Transaction you are running is INSERT OVERWRITE which works similarly to Truncate and load; the data is seen only when the transaction is complete.
The command to view the default isolation level in Snowflake is

```
SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'TRANSACTION_DEFAULT_ISOLATION_LEVEL' IN ACCOUNT;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just so I noticed, PARAMATERS should be PARAMETERS.